# Find all the solutions of the differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to find all the solutions of the differential equation $y'+2y=b(x), x \in \mathbb{R}$ where

$$b(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
1-|x| &, |x| \leq 1 \\ \\
0 &, |x|>1 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

That's what I have tried:

$$a(x)=2, \text{ thus } A(x)= \int_0^x 2 dt=2x$$

So if $\phi$ is a solution of the differential equation, then:

$$e^{2x} \phi'(x)+ 2 e^{2x} \phi(x)= e^{2x} b(x) \Rightarrow (e^{2x} \phi(x))'=e^{2x} b(x) \\ \Rightarrow \int_0^x (e^{2t} \phi(t))' dt=\int_0^x e^{2t} b(t) dt \Rightarrow e^{2x} \phi(x)- \phi(0)=\int_0^x e^{2t} b(t) dt$$

$$\int_0^x e^{2t} b(t) dt=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\int_0^x e^{2t} (1-t)dt & , 0<x<1\\ 
\int_0^x e^{2t}(1+t)dt & , -1<x<0\\ 
\int_0^1 e^{2t} (1-t)dt & , x \geq 1\\ 
\int_0^{-1} e^{2t}(1+t)dt  &  , x\leq-1
\end{matrix}\right.$$

And thus:

$$\phi(x)= e^{-2x} \phi(0)+ e^{-2x} g(x)$$

where:

$$g(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{3e^{2x}-2xe^{2x}-3}{4} &, 0<x<1 \\ \\
\frac{e^{2x}+2xe^{2x}-1}{4} &, -1<x<0 \\ \\
\frac{3e^{2}-2xe^{2}-3}{4} & , x \geq 1 \\ \\
\frac{e^{-2}-2e^{-2}-1}{4} & , x \leq -1
\end{matrix}\right.$$

So the general solution of the differential equation is:

$$y(x)= c e^{-2x}+e^{-2x} g(x)$$

Could you tell me if that what I have tried is right?

Comment: That looks correct! Well done.  To verify the solution, substitute it into the original ODE and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just have started solving 
$$
y'+2y=ax+b
$$
with the trial solution $y(x)=Ax+B+Ce^{-2x}$ leading to $y'=A-2Ce^{-2x}$ and
$$
A+2Ax+2B=ax+b\implies A=a/2,\; B=b/2-a/4
$$
and then patch together a continuously differentiable solution from pieces for each of the 4 intervals of linearity of $\max(0,1-|x|)$.

Comment: what matters is the particular solution in the form $Ax + B.$